# Need explanation of Elliptic Curve Key Pair Generation code

Tags: java, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I am trying to implement an ECC curve basec program and I saw this code on their official page

```
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec;
...
ECCurve curve = new ECCurve.Fp(
    new BigInteger("883423532389192164791648750360308885314476597252960362792450860609699839"), // q
    new BigInteger("7fffffffffffffffffffffff7fffffffffff8000000000007ffffffffffc", 16), // a
    new BigInteger("6b016c3bdcf18941d0d654921475ca71a9db2fb27d1d37796185c2942c0a", 16)); // b

ECParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECParameterSpec(
    curve,
    curve.decodePoint(Hex.decode("020ffa963cdca8816ccc33b8642bedf905c3d358573d3f27fbbd3b3cb9aaaf")), // G
    new BigInteger("883423532389192164791648750360308884807550341691627752275345424702807307")); // n

KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
```

Now, I need to specify my own parameters. I have `a`, `b` and `q` (value of field) and also a generator point (x,y). Now this code has a single value `G`, not in (x,y) - how do they get this value? Also how can find the value of `n` which has been used here in this code?

Precisely I need to know that given values of `a`, `b`, `q` and a (x,y) point, how can the values of `G` and `n` have been generated?

Comment: Urgent you say. A lack of planning on your part is not our responsibility? With that said, did you ask them? Were they unable to explain it to you? Did you then google for an explanation? Did you read the rest of their code? Did that not explain it?

Comment: No, it does not explain that how to get these G and n if you are defining your own curve. I guess these G and n are for predefined curves which are built in. But they gave this code for Explicitly defined parameters, that is why I am confused.

Comment: You might want to finish reading the page this code was cut and pasted from: http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Elliptic+Curve+Key+Pair+Generation+and+Key+Factories It explains how to use this.

Comment: I guess you are still not getting my point. The values of a, b, q,n and G are given using (perhaps) prime192v1 built-in curve specification. In the Ecc curve, if you are going to define your values of a,b, and q then you have to give values of G and n. I was wondering is there anyway that if I define my curve and its specifications then G and n can be calculated? From where those values of a,b, n, G have come? Just sort of example values???

Comment: The answer here should have been: you need both a prime field (usually p, as in F(p)) and an order field (n or q). The size of the order field (as unsigned integer) is the same as the key size. The point G consist of an identifier for the point encoding, and the encoding. Usually the identifier is a byte with the value `04` which means that an uncompressed point encoding is used. Then you get your x and y, encoded as octet strings with the same length as the key size (rounded up to the nearest byte of course). The x and y should be in uncompressed big integer encoding.